# What should I do to exclude my program from reading empty lines in text files but still include spaces

Tags: python, arrays, file

```
#read the data from the file
#takes in file name
def readFile(fileName):
    myFile=open(fileName,"r")
    #reading the lines in the file and returning the data skips the first line
    fileData=myFile.readlines()[1:]
    myFile.close()
    myNewList = []
    numRow = 0
    numCol = 0
    emptyLines = 0
    #from 0 to the length of the file data list
    for i in range(0,len(fileData),1):
        #creating a empty list for each row of data if the line is not empty
        if fileData[i].strip() != "":
            myNewList.append([])
        #checks for empty lines
        if fileData[i].strip() == "":
            emptyLines = emptyLines + 1 
        numRow = numRow + 1
        #if file data at a certain index with no spaces dosen't equal a empty line
        if fileData[i].strip() != NEWLINE:
            #removing spaces and splitting data by spaces
            myElements=fileData[i].strip().split(SPACE)
            myElements=fileData[i].split()
            for j in range(0,len(myElements),1):
                numCol = len(myElements)
                if myElements[j].strip() != SPACE:
                    myNewList[i].append(int(myElements[j]))
```

```
#calculating and displaying the total
def display(myList,numRow,numCol):
    total = 0

    #loops 7 times for just the first 7 numbers but in every row
    for i in range(0,numRow,1):
        total = 0
        for j in range(0,numCol,1):
            if j < 7:
                if myList[i][j] != "":
                    print("%s" %myList[i][j], end = "-")
                    total = total + myList[i][j]
        print("Total=%s"%total)
```

what would I need to do to exclude empty lines with no spaces from being added into the 2d array. I had a way to exclude them from if there are empty lines at the bottom of the text file but not for the middle. I basically want the program to not include empty lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this to

```
fileData=myFile.readlines()[1:]
```

this

```
fileData = [line.strip() for line in myFile.readlines()[1:] if line.strip()]
```

Looping through each line of the file and checking for the empty lines using `if line.strip()` it will return `False` if it's an empty line. if it's not adding that line to the list `fileData`.

**Using for loop:**

```
fileData = []
for line in fp.readlines()[1:]:
    if line.strip():
        fileData.append(line.strip())
```

Comment: could you explain what is going on in this ?

Comment: if you want i can simplify your code just share sample of data in your file

Comment: how would I change this statement to also include empty lines that contain spaces

Comment: it will only remove empty lines it doesn't remove spaces

Comment: but what if my line only has spaces

Comment: say this is the raw data from my list
but I just want it to exclude '\n' and include those with just spaces

Comment: if it has only spaces it will consider as empty line only

Comment: nevermind I got it I had something wrong in my program thanks for the help by the way